# Probability of getting 5 heads with 10 coin flips

Tags: probability

So, when I started thinking about this problem I tried to do $(0.5)^5\cdot (0.5)^5$ because 5 of the flips are heads and the remaining 5 are tails.

However, I searched the answer and it's actually:
$\binom{10}{5}(0.5)^5(0.5)^5$

I was wondering why the $\binom{10}{5}$ is in front of my previous answer. Does anyone have an explanation as to why?

Comment: in the case that you have a weighted coin, or some other event with probability, the probability of k successes out of n trials is nCk * p^k * (1-p)^(n-k) nice clean formula

Comment: @EthanBolker he's looking for the probability, not the number of ways to flip 5 heads

Comment: @SakethMalyala Right thanks. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to flip $10$ coins and obtain $5$ heads.

One possible way would be HHHHHTTTTT and another, equally likely one is HTHTHTHTHT.

So how many sequences are there? It turns out that if we have $10$ flips, we can *choose* $5$ of them to be heads, and the rest would be tails, hence $10$ choose $5$.

Comment: could you have justified this using the multinomial theorem?

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{10}{5}$ is the number of ways you choose the 5 coins that are heads.

Comment: wait but then if ur choosing then where does the probability come from?